# thunderbird - email signature from apple mail to thunderbird is one line

Tags: html, email, signature, thunderbird, apple-mail

The footer in Apple Mail looks good, after sending to Outlook, Gmail is ok. Probelm appears in Thuinderbird. There, each of the poems appears on one line and not below each other. What is wrong? I've probably tried everything and I can't figure out what's wrong. The same footer sent from Outlook in Thunderbird is ok, from Thunderbird to Apple or Outlook is also ok.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>stopka_mailowa_DFTL</title>
 </head>
 <style>
        div { display: table-cell; max-width: 760px; display: block }
     
    </style>
 <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,200,300,400,500,600&display=swap&subset=latin-ext');
 </style>
</html>

<div style="float:left" align="left">
<table width="100%" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 760px; table-layout: fixed;">
 <tr>
   <td width="70%" height="13" align="left" >
    <p style="
    table-layout: fixed;
    font-size:23px; 
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    font-style: normal;
    color:#000000; 
    margin-bottom:6px; 
    margin-top:0px; 
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;">

    Imie i Nazwisko
    </p> 
    </td>
  
  <td width="30%" align="right">
      <p align="right" style="margin-top:0px; table-layout: fixed;">
    <img src="" width="212" height="41" alt=""/>
   </p>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 760px; margin-top: -15PX, table-layout: fixed;" height="50">
 <tr>
   <td width="5%" height="10%">
   <p style="margin-top:9px; margin-right: 9px;table-layout: fixed;">
    <img src="http://www.inblue-robocza4.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Bez-nazwy-1_Obszar-roboczy-1.png" width="26" height="2" alt=""/> 
   </p>
    </td>
  <td width="95%" height="14%" >
   <span style=
     "font-size:13px; 
     color:#686968; 
      table-layout: fixed;
     text-align: left;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     font-weight:400;
     font-style: normal;
     letter-spacing:0.5px;
     line-height:25px">
     Lorem Ipsum
   </span> </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table width="100%" align="left" style="margin-top: -20px;">
 <tr>
   <td width="10%" height="12px">
    <p style=
     "font-size:13px; 
      table-layout: fixed;
     color:#686968;  
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     font-weight:400;
     font-style: normal;
      text-align:justify;
     margin-bottom:-10px; 
     margin-top:22px;  
     line-height: 18px;
     letter-spacing: 0.5px;"
   > 
         
       +48 000 000 000
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       
       <br>
     
             <a href="" style="color:#1b529f">
        mail@sent.pl</a></p>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table width="100%" align="left">
 <tr>
  <td width="10%" height="30px">
      <img src="http://www.inblue-robocza4.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Bez-nazwy-1_Obszar-roboczy-1.png" width="26" height="2" alt="" align="right"/>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table width="100%" align="left" style="margin-top: -30px;">
 <tr>
   <td width="50%" height="12px">
    <span style=
     "font-size:9px; 
     color:#686968; 
      table-layout: fixed;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     font-weight:400;
     font-style: normal;
     margin-bottom: -20px;
     margin-top: -80px;
     letter-spacing:0.5px">
     <a href="www..pl" style="color:#1b529f">www.lorem.pl </a>| ul. Ipsum 8, 00-000 Lorem
    </span>
  </td>
  <td width="50%">
   <p align="right">
    <span style=
     "
     font-size:9px; 
     color:#686968; 
      table-layout: fixed;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     font-weight:400;
     font-style: normal;
     margin-bottom: -20px;
     margin-top: -80px;
     letter-spacing:0.5px">
        |      |   
    </span>
   </p>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table width="100%" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
  <td  height="20px">
   <p style= "margin-top:-25px; table-layout: fixed; margin-bottom: -25px" >
      <img src="http://www.inblue-robocza4.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Bez-nazwy-1_Obszar-roboczy-1-1.png" width="759" height="20" alt=""/>
   </p>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table width="100%" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
  <td width="100%">
   <p align="left">
   <p style=
      "font-size: 9px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    font-style: normal;
    margin-top: -30px;
    text-align: justify;
    color:#686968; ">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <br><br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."


        </p>
   </p>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```